# How do I get the pixel value width of a custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, size

I am trying to get the pixel value width of a custom lightning component. So far the closest I've gotten to a width is descriptive values like SMALL, MEDIUM, and LARGE via `lightning:flexipageRegionInfo`

Any retrievals from document or the `DOM` fail because of `SecureDocument` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your own width by putting an empty div somewhere in your component:

```
<div aura:id="measurement" />
```

---

```
var width = component.find("measurement").getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

---

Note that this won't work in "init" because rendering hasn't occurred yet, but you can do so immediately afterwards using setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(
        function() {
            var width = component.find("space").getElement().getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }
    )
);
```

The SecureComponent API has limits, but as long as you stay with normal HTML or your own custom components, you can get this measurement.